# Pandas to_latex without tabular environment?

Tags: pandas

I would like to convert a pandax dataframe to latex but  I don't want to have the tabular environment around. Is there a way to remove the `\begin{tabular}` environment and just leave the table separated by ampersands and double backslashes?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.to_latex(index=False,header=False,decimal=',') 
#still creates a tabular enviroment.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function hasn't been implemented yet, you would have to create a pull Request. See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37443